# Error trying to use keyboard and mouse control methods at the same time with pynput

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, mouse, pynput

I'm having problems because Controller names match for both mouse and keyboard, so try doing this.

```py
import pynput

mouseController = pynput.mouse.Controller
mouseButton = pynput.mouse.Button

keyboardController = pynput.keyboard.Controller
keyboardKey = pynput.keyboard.Key

keyboardController.press (keyboardKey.space)
keyboardController.release (keyboardKey.space)

mouseController.click (mouseButton.left, 2)
```

But it is giving me this argument error, that if I used them importing directly to each one it would not happen

```
keyboardController.press(keyboardKey.space)
TypeError: press() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of [pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/) the controllers should be instantiated

```py
mouseController = pynput.mouse.Controller()

keyboardController = pynput.keyboard.Controller()
```